# What is the actual meaning of Inclusive ordered comparison in python version

Tags: python, pip

I have this specified in my constraints file

`asgiref==3.5.0`

and when I run pip3 install during docker build, it complains about

```
#12 24.67 ERROR: Cannot install -r /tmp/requirements.txt (line 16) because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
#12 24.67 
#12 24.67 The conflict is caused by:
#12 24.67     django 3.2.11 depends on asgiref<4 and >=3.3.2
#12 24.67     The user requested (constraint) asgiref==3.5.0
#12 24.67 
#12 24.67 To fix this you could try to:
#12 24.67 1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
#12 24.67 2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
#12 24.67 
#12 24.67 ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

Pip3 version is 21.2.4, Linux version is 18.04, Python 3.6.9

Maybe I have been misunderstanding the `>=` for the whole time, I would have thought `asgiref==3.5.0` would fit the `asgiref<4 and >=3.3.2` condition?

The pip3 install runs fine if I specify `asgiref==3.3.3` or `asgiref==3.4.0`

I have the 3.5.0 installed locally fine

[image]

[image]

Comment: On my machine with Python 3.9, installing `django==3.2.11` installs `asgiref==3.5.0` by itself without any problem ([see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvfgP.png)). Test it with a clean virtual environment.

Comment: @H4iku I got the problem when building the docker image, pretty sure it was clean. Pip version is 21.2.4

Comment: Is the specific version you requested actually available on the platform where you have a problem? Why not specify `asgiref>=3.3.2` for your own requirements as well, do you require the latest?

Comment: You are right, it's the same problem I had this morning again, it cannot find version `3.5.0` but I have it installed locally for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I should delete my question, but I think I will put an answer to it so in case someone else encountered the same problem, I believe the culprit is during docker build it cannot find the version specified:

```
 > [ 8/12] RUN set -ex && pip3 install -I asgiref==3.5.0:                                                                                                  
#12 0.250 + pip3 install -I asgiref==3.5.0                                                                                                                 
#12 0.825 Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple                                                                             
#12 1.051 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement asgiref==3.5.0 (from versions: 0.8, 0.9, 0.9.1, 0.10.0, 0.11.0, 0.11.1, 0.11.2, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.13.0, 0.13.2, 0.13.3, 0.14.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 2.2.0, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.1.4, 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 3.2.4, 3.2.5, 3.2.6, 3.2.7, 3.2.8, 3.2.9, 3.2.10, 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 3.3.3, 3.3.4, 3.4.0, 3.4.1)
#12 1.052 ERROR: No matching distribution found for asgiref==3.5.0
```

I don't know why it can't find the version though, maybe the version is specific to the OS/Python. But I checked the [pypi index](https://pypi.org/simple/asgiref/) it seems the version is there and not tied to a specific OS:

[image]

Regardless, the error message was a bit confusing, should have said it can't find the version instead of "conflicting version"

I have fallen on this trap twice today, first time was my bad I set a wrong version for a package. But the second time(this question) I didn't realise it's the same problem since I have the version installed locally.

Comment: The reason why it can't find `asgiref==3.5.0` is your Python version. [It requires Python 3.7 or higher](https://github.com/django/asgiref/tree/3.5.0#dependencies).

Comment: @H4iku thanks, I thought if requires 3.7 the filename would be py37 or something?

Comment: The package is not Python 3.7 specific. They only dropped support for Python 3.6 since it has reached its [end-of-life](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0494/#lifespan).

Comment: Cool ah yeah makes sense. haha